# Update control view in angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive, directive

I've written a directive to use fileupload control in angularjs. I am using it in several places in my application (even it's used twice in a single page). When I upload a file I display the name of that file with a remove button. The problem is that when I upload a file both the instances in same page are updated to display same file name and remove button whereas it should be displayed on the instance through which I've updated the file. 
Appreciate any help. Thanks
Here's my code:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('testmodule')
        .directive('fileUpload', fileUpload);
    fileUpload.$inject = ['$upload', '$http'];
    function fileUpload($upload, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                tElement.append(

                       '<div id="notadded" ng-show="!setDocumentAvailability(purpose, getAttachedFilesObject())">' +
                           '<div ng-file-drop ng-model="files" class="drop-box" drag-over-class="{accept:\'dragover\', reject:\'dragover-err\', delay:100}"' +
                            'multiple="true" allow-dir="true" accept="image/*">' +
                                '<button ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files, purpose)" ng-model="files" multiple="true" class="' + tAttrs.setbuttonclass + '">' +
                                '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Upload' +
                                '</button>' +
                                '<p ng-show="invalidFile" class="help-block">{{errorMessage}}</p>' +
                           '</div>' +
                       '</div>'); return { post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                            scope.onFileSelect = function ($files, purpose) {
                            var $file = $files[0],
                                fileType = scope.getFileType($file);
                                if ($file.size > 0) {
                                $upload
                                    .upload({
                                        url: 'testurl' + purpose + '?fileType=' + fileType[1],
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        file: $file
                                    })
                                    .then(
                                        function (data, status, headers, config) {

                                                angular.forEach(data.data, function (file) {
                                                    attachedFiles.push(file);
                                                });
                                            } else {
                                                growlFactory.error();
                                            }
                                            scope.setAttachedFilesObject(attachedFiles);
                                            scope.setDocumentAvailability(purpose, attachedFiles);

                                            var thisAttachedFiles = scope.getAttachedFilesObject();
                                            var updatedTemplate = '';
                                                if (scope.setDocumentAvailability(scope.purpose, thisAttachedFiles)) {
                                                    updatedTemplate = updatedTemplate.concat('<div id="added">');

                                                for (var i = 0; i < thisAttachedFiles.length; i++) {
                                                    updatedTemplate = updatedTemplate.concat('<div>');  


                                                    if (thisAttachedFiles[i].Purpose == purpose) {
                                                        updatedTemplate = updatedTemplate.concat( 
                                                            '<div class="row">');


                                                            updatedTemplate = updatedTemplate.concat(
                                                                '<div class="col-xs-6">' +
                                                                '<div class="thumbnail"><img src="' + scope.getCompleteImageUrl() + '"/></div>' +
                                                                '</div>');
                                                        }
                                                        updatedTemplate = updatedTemplate.concat('<div class="col-xs-6">' +
                                                                    '<p>File attached:<br />' + thisAttachedFiles[i].OriginalFileName + '</p>' +
                                                                    '<button id="remove" ng-click="scope.removeFile(scope.purpose, scope.getAttachedFilesObject())" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Remove</button>' +
                                                                '</div>');


                                                        updatedTemplate = updatedTemplate.concat('</div>');
                                                    }

                                                    updatedTemplate = updatedTemplate.concat('</div>');
                                            }

                                                updatedTemplate = updatedTemplate.concat('</div>');
                                                } 
                                            iElement.find('div#notadded').replaceWith(updatedTemplate);



                                            growlFactory.success();
                                        });
                            } 
                        };
```

I've put only relevant code for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself. Whenever we want to use multiple instance of a directive we have to define isolated scope. In the above code adding

```
scope: true,
```

after

```
restrict: 'E',
```

worked for me.